# Android: scaling and position of widgets in RelativeLayout wrt background image

Tags: android, image, background, android-relativelayout, scaling

I have a RelativeLayout with a background PNG. The background PNG has a header in it. In the RelativeLayout I place widgets inside this header.

The problem starts when this scales to a larger device: The header in the background PNG stretches, causing the widgets to be positioned too high within the header. Because I specify my relative layout positioning in "dp", I would expect the widgets to be repositioned proportionally to the scaling of the background image and fall into place automagically.

Here a simplified version of my RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="26dp"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:background="@drawable/home_bg"
    android:paddingRight="12dp"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcome_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="142dp"
        android:text="@string/home_11"
        android:textColor="@color/tile_points_white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I know I can fix the header-height in a 9-patch background PNG (thats what I do now), but I rather have my headers scale vertically too.

How can I specify that my widgets should be repositioned proportionally to the scaling of the background PNG?

Cheers,
Andrej

Comment: Perhaps an screenshot of what you are trying to achieve will help...

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```